# Swift NSTimer passing variable syntax

Tags: swift, nstimer

I want to call a function myTestFunction(day), were day is an int, from an NSTimer.

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.myTestFunction(_:)), userInfo: day, repeats: true)
```

The Xcode compiler has prompted me towards the above syntax, but when I put tests in the func it doesn't appear to be called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The method specified in the `selector` parameter accepts only one parameter which must be of type `NSTimer`. The documentation says: *The timer passes itself as the argument*.

```
func myTestFunction(timer : NSTimer) {
```

Anything else (aside from no parameter) does not work.

But you can get your passed integer via `userInfo` for example

```
let day = timer.userInfo as! Int
```

Comment: I thought the idea of the userInfo: option was to allow you to pass variable(s)/Dictionaries to the function initiated by NSTimer?

Comment: Yes, that's the right way, but not via the direct parameter  like `testFunction(day)`. Get the userInfo object with `timer.userInfo`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm being thick, what you're suggesting seems to lose the typical NSTimer construct (e.g. NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1,..) so don't see where I tell it the timer interval or the repeat etc.

Comment: No, just use the syntax in your question and declare the callback method like in my answer. The passed timer instance holds the `userInfo` parameter containing your integer value.